# What is the SharePoint "Restricted View" Permission level in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, irm, sharepoint-permissions

When I check the permission level's for my site collection at .../_layouts/15/role.aspx I **do not** see the "Restricted View" Permission Level (see below). [image: .../_layouts/15/role.aspx Permission Levels]

However, when I go to a specific library on the root site and select a listed user (or group), click **Edit User Permissions** I'm brought to .../sites/mysite/_layouts/15/editprms.aspx. From here I *do* see the "Restricted View" Permission Level. (see below). [image]

I'm trying to copy the library's configurations over to another library in a different site collection and I need to use the "Restricted View" permission level in this other library, but it isn't showing up in this other site collection's settings nor this other library's settings.

Where did it come from? Can I recreate it manually? What permissions does it grant?

The end goal for me is that I want to create a library and permission it so that some users can only view documents in the application (using a combination of IRM and these native library permission settings)- I don't want them to be able to download it offline or take screenshots or open in the browser. I'm happy to use some other combination of configurations to accomplish this goal. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I search a lot for the permission level. My observation was that "Restricted View" is a hidden permission level (can be seen only while giving permission) which is available ONLY in TEAM SITE collection. I checked dev, communication and app catalogue for the permission level but could not find it there.

You can even create your own custom permission level choosing what you need in it to meet your requirements.

Or create a team site and add this library where you want to give this permission in this site.

Comment: Hi @harshal, thank you for the response! Unfortunately, this doesn't fix my issue. If you look back at my original post the issue I'm having is that when I go to the root site's role.aspx page at ".../_layouts/15/role.aspx" **I do not see the "Restricted View" permission setting**... I only see it when I go to a library on that site --> library settings --> permissions --> edit permissions that I see the "Restricted View" permission. So I'm not able to check the permissions it has and I'm not able to recreate it correctly. Again, the screenshots in my original post show this. Any ideas?

Comment: Right, but I then have no way of seeing the right permission associated with this permission level. Without that I am not able to recreate the behavior correctly. Do you see my dilemma? Any advice?

Comment: I just checked and my test site where I see the "Restricted View" permission is actually a communication site. When I tried making a Team site the "Restricted View" Permission wasn't there... I made another communication site in my test environment and the "Restricted View" option is actually missing too...

So I'm at a loss, I must have configured my one test site to enable this somehow but I don't know how. And this permission level seems to be the key to locking down the library correctly (I want to only open files in the client app with full IRM features enabled).

Comment: I compared everywhere and I couldn't find any differences. I have no idea where the "Restricted View" came from! Here's an article where they seem to have given up to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/restricted-view-and-view-only-permission-level-on/aafccbbd-70d3-42ca-9bba-147d6daeed82

Comment: Did you create a team site and check if the permission level is available?

Comment: Yes, and it's not!

Answer (score 0):

Restricted view is not a built-in permission level. It shall be a custom one and being deleted by another user in that site.

As it is a custom permission level, simply re-create it with all your required permissions. It can be easily done. Just like harshal said, first go to site which has restricted view permission and check the permissions it has. Then create the same permission level in your target library/site.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @jerry_MSFT, thank you for the response! Unfortunately, this doesn't fix my issue. If you look back at my original post the issue I'm having is that when I go to the root site's role.aspx page at ".../_layouts/15/role.aspx" **I do not see the "Restricted View" permission setting**... I only see it when I go to a library on that site --> library settings --> permissions --> edit permissions that I see the "Restricted View" permission. So I'm not able to check the permissions it has and I'm not able to recreate it correctly. Again, the screenshots in my original post show this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The "Restricted View" Permission only shows up once there are files in the document library. If you start from an empty library you will never see the permission until a file gets added.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the restricted view permissions is only available to assign to an individual user, not a share-point group.

Thanks!

Comment: It can be added to a group, it seems

Answer (score 0):

To make the 'restricted view' permission available for the library

1. Put any file into the document library
2. Disable inheritance for that file in SharePoint settings
3. Restricted View permission now available for library and can be assigned to user, domain group...etc.

Only tested with Teams channel permissions, don't know if this works with non-Teams SharePoint site